# MPU6000 CS pin using I2C

Tags: i2c

I've designed my own board using the MPU6000. I am using it in I2C mode. Using both Adafruit's MPU6050 code and the (common) I2C scanner code with Arduino the device is not recognised. I think it has to do with the CS pin. In the datasheet it says (0=SPI mode) in the pin descriptions but I can't see anything about I2C and the typical operating circuit schematic leaves CS floating.

When using the MPU6000 in I2C mode should CS be ground or VCC?

Attached is my circuit. VCC is 3.3V and verified on the physical board.

[image]

Comment: in the chapter 7.13 in the datasheet it demonstrates an I2C connection which has connected the CS pin to VDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using the MPU6000 in I2C mode should CS be ground or VCC?

Consider the information you know:

> In the datasheet it says (0=SPI mode) in the pin descriptions

Clearly, you would not want it to be tied to ground for I2C mode.

So the question then becomes, should it be floating or high?

The safe solution is to place a resistor footprint tying it high; you can then either install that component or not.

Most likely you want to tie it high through a 0-ohm resistor.

If you want your board to also support the related MPU6050, you probably want to have provisions for the bypass capacitor which that requires, as in that case pin 8 is actually a power supply.

Keep in mind also that the MPU-6000 is an old product not recommended for new designs.

Answer (score 0):

CS should be tied to VCC (3.3V). Works perfectly now.